# Set-Cookie not working in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, asp.net-core, setcookie, antiforgerytoken

I have one strange issue, one of the site I have developed returns Anti-Forgery cookie while requesting login page. When I check response in chrome network tab it contains header

```
Set-Cookie: .AspNetCore.Antiforgery.w5W7x28NAIs=xxx; path=/; samesite=strict; httponly
```

But when I check cookie value in Application tab (Under cookie section), I cant find any cookie set in browser. I have also checked cookies with chrome extensions like EditThisCookie but it is also not displaying there.

Network Tab:
[image]

Application Tab:
[image]

Am I missing some simple thing, or this is some kind of chrome (Version 66.0.3359.181 (Official Build) (64-bit)) bug?

Comment: See [Insecure cookies not being sent if secure cookie of same name exists](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=843371).

Answer (score 3):

I've got similar issue, solved it by setting `withCredentials = true` for every requests.

For angular, this basically means:

```
this.http.get(url, {  withCredentials: true  });
```